# Solr at http://x.x.x.x:8988/solr not online

Tags: solr

We have recently upgrade new solr version (solr-9.0.0) and we are facing following issue:-

```
[dev solr-9.0.0]$ bin/init.d/solr status -p 8988
Solr at http://192.168.100.225:8988/solr not online
```

We have added host ip (192.168.100.225) with SOLR_HOST in solr configuration file.

Could you please help us how we can resolve it?

Comment: Is there a Solr instance running? (`ps aux` shows all processes running for that user) - Does the Solr log say anything useful?

Comment: @MatsLindh, Thanks for your reply.

Yes it is working for http://localhost:8988/solr/ but it is not working for my host IP (192.168.100.225).

I have added following in solr-9.0.0/bin/solr.in.sh file
SOLR_HOST="192.168.100.225"
SOLR_PORT=8988
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Djetty.host=192.168.100.225"

Comment: Did you have those parameters present when you started Solr? If you only added them later, Solr won't bind to the correct ip on startup.

Comment: Seems like your solr needs to be restarted. Try to kill solr by checking ps -aux if present. If your issue still persist then you are doing wrong configuration and solr is not getting up

Answer (score 3):

I Faced the similar issue when i upgraded my Solr nodes from Solr 8.8.2 to Solr 9.

After several weeks of retry and config updates .Below fix worked for me.

Fix

Try adding below system property in your solr.in.sh file inside bin folder.

SOLR_JETTY_HOST="0.0.0.0"

If this fix didnt work you can get help from below slack channel from where my issue got fixed with the help of a bunch of solr dev community.

[https://join.slack.com/t/apachesolr/shared_invite/zt-1azru9w77-E8QwYsnew~TtlU5f6PDFDg](https://join.slack.com/t/apachesolr/shared_invite/zt-1azru9w77-E8QwYsnew%7ETtlU5f6PDFDg)

Comment: While this link you answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This indeed fixed my broken hopes! thanks